# Babylonjs : Synchronize multiple objects in multiple canvases

Tags: javascript, vue.js, 3d, synchronization, babylonjs

:) Hello !

I'm working on a project where we have to display differents objects (.obj files) in order to compare them. The tricky point is that we have to synchronize movements between them !

**Which stack ?**

- Vue 3
- TypeScript
- Babylon.js 5.0.0-alpha.44
- Babylon.js loaders 5.0.0-alpha.44

**Which structure ?**

- Each object is in a separated canvas (easier for me to manage the UI and the users actions).
- Each object is initialized by a new instance of `ViewerService` (the class initializing the engine, the scene and loading the object).
- To manage the synchronization, I have a GlobalViewerService (a singleton in the application). This class interacts with user events and each synchronized ViewerService.

[UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhzLR.png)

[Controls screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hKsT.png)

1. For `addSynchronizedCanvas()` and `removeSynchronizedCanvas()` (see code below)
2. For `setLeadCanvas()` and `unsetLeadCanvas()` (see code below)

**How to manage synchronization ?**

The synchronization can be toggled by buttons.
We set the lead canvas with a button and the others canvases are following it.

I have tried differents things to make the synchronization work but two principles have retained my attention :

- Listen to pointer events on the lead canvas, clone the events and dispatch them to the following canvases : very simple and easy to implement, but at every dispatched event the focus was dispatching too...

  - The lead canvas don't keep the focus and it's breaking the synchronization !
- For each following canvas : set the `engine.inputElement` with the lead canvas (idea from [babylon documentation](https://doc.babylonjs.com/divingDeeper/scene/multiCanvas#events)). It was not working great : the pointer events was buggy. To fix this, two things :

  - I create a "control" canvas over the lead canvas. This is the one to controll the following canvases. Without it, the lead canvas don't move :(
  - I listen to a keyboard event. Keypress = set `engine.inputElement` and `camera` control. Keyup = reset `engine.inputElement` and `camera` control.

    - It works ! But it's not convenient for the user : kreypress"s", keep "s" pressed, click with the mouse to do the manipulation, keyup "s" to end the manipulation.

**Demo !**

You can see the mouse events but keep in mind that I'm triggering the keyboard between manipulations too ;)

[Demo gif recorded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkrqs.gif)

**My questions**

- Is there a trick to dispatch the events without dispatching the focus ?
- Any tips to improve the user experience ?
- Any better solution to synchronize these canvases ?

I hope everything was clear, don't hesitate to ask me question about the code or the user actions !
Thank you and have a great day :)

**Code interesting for you in `GlobalViewerService` :**

Almost everything.

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */

import ViewerService from './ViewerService';

export default class GlobalViewerService {
  public synchronizedCanvases: Map<string, HTMLCanvasElement> = new Map();

  public viewerServices: Map<string, ViewerService> = new Map();

  public leadCanvas: { id: string, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement } | undefined = undefined;

  public controlCanvas: HTMLCanvasElement | undefined = undefined;

  public scrollableContainer: HTMLElement | undefined = undefined;

  public oldScroll: number | undefined = undefined;

  private synchronized = false;

  constructor() {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', this.synchronize);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', this.desynchronize);
  }

  private synchronize = (event: any) => {
    if (event.key && event.key === 's') {
      if (!this.synchronized) {
        this.synchronized = true;
        if (this.controlCanvas) {
          this.viewerServices.forEach((viewer) => {
            viewer.resetCanvasControl();
            if (this.controlCanvas) {
              viewer.setCanvasControl(this.controlCanvas);
            }
          });
          this.controlCanvas.classList.add('active');
          this.controlCanvas.focus();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private desynchronize = (event: any) => {
    if (event.key && event.key === 's') {
      this.synchronized = false;
      this.viewerServices.forEach((viewer) => {
        viewer.resetCanvasControl();
      });
      if (this.controlCanvas) {
        this.controlCanvas.blur();
        if (this.leadCanvas) {
          this.leadCanvas.canvas.focus();
        }
        this.controlCanvas.classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
  };

  public addViewerService = (id:string, viewer: ViewerService) => {
    this.viewerServices.set(id, viewer);
  }

  public removeViewerService = (id:string) => {
    this.viewerServices.delete(id);
  }

  public setLeadCanvas = (id: string, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
    this.leadCanvas = {
      id,
      canvas,
    };
    if (canvas.parentElement) {
      // Create a new canvas over the lead canvas to control the synchronization
      // Necessary for the lead canvas to move too
      const controlCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      controlCanvas.id = `${id}_control`;
      controlCanvas.classList.add('control-canvas');
      canvas.parentElement.appendChild(controlCanvas);
      this.controlCanvas = controlCanvas;
    }
  }

  public unsetLeadCanvas = () => {
    if (this.leadCanvas) {
      if (this.controlCanvas) {
        this.controlCanvas.remove();
        this.controlCanvas = undefined;
      }
      this.leadCanvas = undefined;
    }
  }

  public addSynchronizedCanvas = (id: string, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, viewer: ViewerService) => {
    this.synchronizedCanvases.set(id, canvas);
    this.viewerServices.set(id, viewer);
  }

  public removeSynchronizedCanvas = (id: string) => {
    const canvas = this.synchronizedCanvases.get(id);
    if (canvas) {
      const viewer = this.viewerServices.get(id);
      if (viewer) {
        viewer.resetCanvasControl();
      }
      this.viewerServices.delete(id);
      this.synchronizedCanvases.delete(id);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Triggerred when we leave the comparator
   */
  public resetAll = () => {
    this.synchronizedCanvases = new Map();
    this.viewerServices = new Map();
    this.controlCanvas = undefined;
    this.leadCanvas = undefined;
    this.scrollableContainer = undefined;
    this.oldScroll = undefined;
    this.synchronized = false;
  }
}
```

**Code interesting for you in `ViewerService` :**

To load an object I use `SceneLoader.Load();`

The functions triggered by the keydown and the keyup events :

```
  public setCanvasControl = (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
    this.camera.detachControl();
    this.scene.detachControl();
    this.engine.inputElement = canvas;
    this.scene.attachControl();
    this.camera.attachControl(canvas);
  }

  public resetCanvasControl = () => {
    this.camera.detachControl();
    this.scene.detachControl();
    this.engine.inputElement = this.canvas;
    this.scene.attachControl();
    this.camera.attachControl(this.canvas);
  }
```

Comment: `Is there a trick to dispatch the events without dispatching the focus`, dispatching it first and then instantly focus the element again should work... Not the best solution I guess. Anyway, I belive your "question" is too broad to be answered. The details are nice though. Best thing you can do is post a single specific question.

Comment: Thank you for your response :)

I have tried to put again the focus on the lead canvas (my first idea to solve the problem), but it's not working great (I think the whole thing break the pointer events for Babylonjs).